# PHP, how do I output the the contents created by another php file to file?

Tags: php

I'm trying to reduce the overhead on our database server. I use a php script to produce sitemaps of all the pages on out site, 80,000.

I want to create a cron job which will run once a week and create static versions of the php sitemap files.

However, I need to loop around and call the sitemap php script and output the contents to a separate file.

How do I output the contents of another php to a file for a cron job ?

EDIT:
I'll also need to wait or sleep a while so I don't bring down the server.

EDIT for Arvin for the flow of the PHP script etc

At the moment I have a sitemap.xml file which is a sitemap index file, which has lot of www.mydomain.com/sitemap.php?start=500&max=500

The sitemap.php take between 1 second and 2 seconds to run and I have a lot of them.

What I'd like to do in a new script is ...

New script

-loop from N = 0 to 100

--output sitemap.php&start=N&max=500

--wait 20 seconds

-end loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your updated details:

```
for($n=0; $n <= 100; $n++) {
   $output = file_get_contents("http://domain.com/sitemap.php?start={$n}&max=500");
   file_put_contents($file, $output);
   sleep(20);
}
```

Comment: @Jules can you add the flow of the program?

Comment: @arvin, I don't understand what you mean ?

Comment: @Jules 'Cause you said, sleep/wait is needed so I'm wondering. If you could list the things that the program will do. or how sitemaps, are generated. I'm guessing that one script generates 1 sitemap, and you got a bunch of these script. Are you trying to make one single script that will run the other one by one? And you mean to sleep while each sitemap is generated?

Comment: @Jules Is the output just one file? And you are appending the content with each iteration?

Comment: @Arvin, good question, I had just planned to output to lots of files. I think the best thing to do is lots of files.

Comment: @Jules Depending on rules set by the server owner. There might be a time limit imposed. If that's the case then you should have a way of saving your progress. Like just storing the `$n` in a separate file and updating it per iteration. That way, run your script every minute or so and initialize the `$n` var from the value from the file.

Answer (score 3):

```
php script.php > anotherfile.txt
```

Or

```
wget -O- http://yoursite/script.php -o/dev/null > anotherfile.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer `wget` too because it can mirror whole sites. But there's also a programmatic way:

```
copy("http://localhost/sitemap.php", "/tmp/sitemap.html");
```

Comment: One problem I didn't think of, see my edit, I'll need to wait / sleep after each so I don't bring down the server.